# How to use a vendor class in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, fine-uploader

I would like to use this package https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/ in my Laravel project. So I modified composer.json file like that:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "fineuploader/php-traditional-server": "1.0.0"
}
```

And run a compose update command. But how can I use `UploadHandler` class (declared in handler.php of the package) on my Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@scipilot answer should work too, but I will give my own choice:

Add this part to Your `composer.json` file and run `composer update`.

```
"files": [
     "vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/handler.php"
]
```

After this, class will be visible in project scope and Your script will work.

---

More about auto loading files in composer here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: When I call `$u = new UploadHandler();` It show `Class 'MyApp\Http\Controllers\UploadHandler' not found`

Comment: @hienbt88 Add backslash in front of `UploadHandler`. Like so: `$u = new \UploadHandler();`

Comment: It will work, but "files" is not the intended nor appropriate mechanism for classes. It's less efficient, less performant and doesn't provide on-demand autoloading. I have updated my answer with these considerations.

Comment: Thanks @scipilot for explanation, I up Your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The package isn't using namespaces or much else the Composer autoload could provide magically for you, so you could either include the class file yourself:

`include "vendor/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/handler.php";`

or as you are using the Composer autoloader in Laravel, you should define a classmap.

In your composer json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["vendor/FineUploader/php-traditional-server"]
    }
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`
(including "vendor/autoload.php" is already provided by the Laravel boot).

All the classes in their library will be auto-loaded at the moment your code requires them.

Update: why classmap is the most suitable method.

Autoloading is the most efficient and performant way to load a class, because it is only parsed, compiled, loaded into memory when the class is actually needed. "Classmap" autoloading is the intended mechanism to load classes which are not in a namespace, or are not in PSR0 or 4 format.

Conversely, using a global (app boot) include set for classes, or similarly using the "files" option in the composer autoloader would be the most inefficient as it would load *all dependencies* for *all application requests*, regardless of whether they are going to be used or not. In fact using autoload "files" for class dependencies is worse than the traditional approach of having specific includes in each of your scripts. At least then you would only pre-loading the specific requirements, thus similar to autoload in memory usage.

The "files" autoload option is intended for flat libraries of functions (not OO), which are simply pre-loaded on all requests, because there is no auto-load mechanism for function calls.

Note the use of op-code caches would soften the efficiency difference between the two, but the memory usage issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use `UploadHandler` directly?
Composer have autoloading feature, so it can pick up your "dependencies" on the fly

Comment: This would only work if the FineUploader package had declared itself properly in its own composer.json. Unfortunately they haven't, so the calling app needs to specifically target the resources. You could submit a pull request to them with the correct autoload specification?